# PayPal solution for SaaS subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, subscription, saas, paypal-subscriptions

My web app requires subscriptions. I'm looking into payment solutions that best work with SaaS scenarios.

I see that PayPal has three options: Standard, Advanced and Pro. I want my app to make API calls to PayPal to check payment status. Which one of these solutions is the best for SaaS subscriptions?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always preferred Payments Pro.  This gives you full freedom to build your apps how you want to.

You'll be able to integrate credit cards directly, so you can build that UI however you want, and then you can use Express Checkout API's for the PayPal payments, which provides more features than Payments Standard does.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I appreciate your response.